# Past and present tense

Tags: past-tense, present-tense

In our High school test there was a question that asked us to identify a mistake:

> She started with some complimentary remarks about the organisers of the conference, and then **proceeded** with her speech.

The answer was to correct "proceeded" into "proceeds". I haven't been able to explain this to myself so please help me.

Comment: It should be _then_, not _than*_. Are you sure _then_ wasn't the answer?

Comment: I've made a typo, i'm so sorry about that. It was "then" in the question

Answer (score 3):

The answer was wrong. In this case, the verb tenses should match:

> She **started** with some complimentary remarks about the organisers of the conference, and then **proceeded** with her speech.

Or:

> She **starts** with some complimentary remarks about the organisers of the conference, and then **proceeds** with her speech.

(Note that I changed *than* to *then*.)

Comment: Oh i'm terribly sorry. I've made a typo. It was "then". I'm so sorry. And thank you so much for the answer.